# Ars Technica Photo Conte$t: Ready, Aim, Shoot

Tags: discussion, contest, ars-technica

**There is currently one Ars Technica Photo Contest running. Please see below.**

- [“**How do I review my own code?**”](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2196/ars-technica-photo-contest-how-do-i-review-my-own-code)

---

Every couple weeks, Stack Exchange chops up some of our best [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) content and sends it to one of our favorite websites: [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/). There, [the syndicated articles](http://arstechnica.com/author/stack-exchange/) receive thousands of views and help tech savvy readers the world over solve the big-picture programming problems they face every day.

But we have a little problem ourselves. We need title photos to accompany these articles. And where better to find high-quality images than right here at [the best photography Q&A site](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) on the net?

**A challenge:**

Starting today, you will periodically see meta posts featuring soon-to-be-syndicated Q&A denoted with the tag [[ars-technica]](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ars-technica). Each of these posts is a contest that functions very much like [Picture of the Week](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured-photo), but with a few exceptions.

**Submission Rules:**

- Images must reflect the question posed, the answer(s) given, or the
  general content represented in the contest Q&A. This may
  not be an easy. Most content from our Programmers site involves
  programming languages and abstract workplace concepts. Get creative. Get technical. But
  keep your submissions professional.
- Images must be 640 x 285 px.
- Limit <strike>one</strike> **TWO** submissions per person per contest.

**Voting Rules:**

- Up votes only. Down votes will not be counted towards a submission's
  final score.
- Vote for the image that you think looks sharp & best represents the
  spirit of the contest Q&A. Remember: these are title images published
  at a major online publication. The more professional the winning
  image appears, the more likely Ars Technica will agree to feature the
  image. The publisher has final say. Reward high-quality submissions.

**The Winner Gets...**

His or her image published along with attribution, including a name and URL of the winner's choosing. **Also, $200.00.**

*Fine Print: In the event of a tie, Ars Technica will choose among the top submissions. Stack Exchange and Ars Technica reserve the right to reject a photo for any reason, or modify the winning photo to make it better fit the Q&A. By submitting to this contest, you are agreeing to license your photo under [CC-BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). This agreement does not apply to versions of the image not submitted.*

Check the top of this page for updates on Ars Technica Photo Contests currently running at this site.