# Ars Technica Photo Contest: "How do I review my own code?"

Tags: discussion, contest, ars-technica

## [Q&A: How do I review my own code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/139321/39006)

**Submission Rules:**

- Images must reflect the question posed, the answer(s) given, or the
  general content represented in the Q&A at the top of this page. Get
  creative. Get technical. But keep your submission professional.
- Images must be 640 x 285 px.
- Limit <strike>one</strike> **TWO** submissions per person per contest.

**Voting Rules:**

- Up votes only. Down votes will not be counted towards a submission's final score.
- Vote for the image that you think looks sharp & best represents the spirit of the Q&A at the top of this page. Remember: these are title images published at a major online publication. The more professional the winning image appears, the more likely [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/) will agree to feature the image. The publisher has final say. Reward high-quality submissions.

**Prize:**

The contestant whose submission has the most up votes at the end of the contest period will win **$200** and have his/her image published (along with a name & URL of his/her choosing) at Ars Technica. In the event of a tie, Ars Technica will choose among top submissions.

Contest ends: **Tuesday, May 8 at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4)**

See [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/ars-technica-photo-contest-ready-aim-shoot) for official rules. Happy hunting.

Comment: Should be interesting!

Comment: @Sam: I still have not received an email yet. What address did you send it to? Hotmail? Gmail? Something else?

Comment: @jrista - hotmail (the email listed in your profile).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### "Self Code Reviewer" C# Function

[image]

Comment: Where's the XML documentation, tsk... :)

Comment: Congrats! You're the winner, as voted on by Ars Technica in a tiebreaker. Check your email inbox for details.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at your own code too long may produce...

[image]

Done in camera, just cropping and contrast in post.

Comment: Close call! But Ars picked your fellow mod in a tiebreaker. Keep an eye out for another contest before long. And thanks for participating!

Comment: @Sam - No worries :D  I even voted his up.

Answer (score 2):

### "Self Code Reviewer" C# Class

[image]

Comment: Had a tough time getting rid of the moire. A bit of desharpening did most of the trick. I can't do anything more to get rid of it entirely.

Comment: Thanks for participating, and better luck next time!

Comment: ...he says to the winner. ;)

Answer (score 2):

### The Classic Way

This is how I review my code, using paper and pencil. Love the classics!

I know it's late now but anyways. The shoot is straight out of the camera with just cropping

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the late addition, but no cigar this time. Better luck next time!